# Java croatian locale

Tags: java, locale

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/locales-137662.html

Here is the list of supported locales for Java.

How do I set them?

The line

```
Locale.setDefault(Locale.CROATIAN);
```

doesn't work, although croatian it's listed as supported. Is there another aproach or way to use it, or do I have to translate manually?

Comment: Could you give more details on why the 'line' does not work?

Comment: Because CROATIAN does not exist as a constant, there is only limited number of languages...

Yet again, it is said croatian IS supported (in the link on the top), so there must be another way...

Answer (score 3):

try: `Locale.setDefault(new Locale("hr", "HR"));`

It is still up to you to support that locale in your application

have a look at the oracle i18n docs [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/resbundle/index.html).

Comment: But it is said it's already supported...

It is also returned from `getAvailableLocales()`: both `hr` and `hr_HR`

Comment: That means your Java runtime has 'hr_HR' installed. The code above represents the croatian locale